# What does "compiler.mobile" to mxmlc actually do?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, mxmlc

There's an option to the Flex compiler mxmlc that's called "compiler.mobile", which is enabled in the airmobile configuration. It is described in the docs as "Specifies that the target runtime is a mobile device", but I'm wondering what effect it actually has. It seems possible to run the built binary on a mobile device (Android pad in this case) no matter if it's true or false.

Thanks

Comment: This is completely unverified but it may be to specify the use of mobile skins and mobile-only components and features (StageVideo, StageWebView and stage text for example)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so... It's possible to specify the Mobile theme and link in the mobile components (DateSpinner etc) even without the mobile flag set. Not 100% sure about those exact components (StageVideo/StageWebView) though.

Comment: It's not a documented option to mxmlc: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html .  Were you referring to something else?  Could this be something just some flag that Flash Builder uses to decide which libraries are available in a mobile project?